# Reusing existing Angular Component inside material Dialog

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I have an existing component `ResultGridComponent` that is passed data by `@Input()`. I want to use the same component for the `MatDialog`. 
Hence I added `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data` in the constructor of the `ResultGridComponent` component.

```
constructor(private spinner: EdpLoaderService, private dialog: MatDialog, @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {}
```

But when the component is called as per it's regular usage that is not as a dialog, I get the following error :

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ResultGridComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ResultGridComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!

I am pretty sure I have imported all the needed modules. Because I created a separate component for the dialog and passed data to it and it worked fine. But I want to reuse the component. And I am pretty sure this error is coming when I call constructor the of the child component as a regular component and the constructor doesn't get the `MatDialogData` passed to it by the caller.

Comment: Hi Satvir, how did you solve this problem? I am exactly same problem, and @Stan's solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 12):

In some cases, I would use @Optional() before the @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA).

```
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) dialogData: any
  ) {
    if (dialogData) {
     // here pass dialog data to the child component
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find a solution to the situation.

---

Problem Statement: I was trying to use the existing component (Let's call it ChildComponent) in 2 separate places. One as a regular child component and second, as a component inside Material Dialog.

---

Challenge: To pass data to the dialog component, we need @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) in the Child Component. But when you inject the ChildComponent inside the regular component, you don't provide any provider for the '@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)'. Hence, it fails while initiating. And we do need the '@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)' if we want to use the ChildComponent inside the Mat Dialog.

---

Solution:
Create a wrapper component, let's call it (ChildWrapperComponent). For the regular use case, directly inject the ChildComponent in the parent component. Whereas for the Mat Dialog use case, provide the ChildWrapperComponent

```
const dialogRef  = this.dialog.open(ChildWrapperComponent, {
                 width: '90%',
                 disableClose: false,
                 data: {
                   fileName: this.fileName,
                   results: this.results
                 }
               } );
```

Now you can have the data inside the ChildWrapperComponent using @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data

```
constructor(private spinner: EdpLoaderService, private dialog: MatDialog,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data,
private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChildWrapperComponent>) {
this.setInputData(data);
```

}

Once you have the data inside the ChildWrapperComponent, inject the Child Component inside the Wrapper and pass data using @Input().

I am a newbie in Angular. Would highly appreciate better or different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding providers like this after reading the [dependency-injection-providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers)

```
@Component({
  ...
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: this },
  ]
})
```

After this, my component reads the data from route resolvers if loaded regularly and reads the data from injected `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` if loaded in dialog in another component.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!
```

Solved by adding @Optional decorator in front of @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) in the component constructor

```
constructor ( @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any ) { }
```

If using `MatDialogRef` add `@Optional()` in front of `MatDialogRef<SomeComponent>` too.