# How to optionally inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an component named customer-edit.component.ts. There is an page which can access customer edit page. However, in other screen, i wish to edit customer but without route to customer page. So i use popup by using mat dialog to achieve that. The pop up was ok, but when I tried to access the screen via customer maintenance screen instead of popup, i hit this

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CustomerEditComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CustomerEditComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!

How can i optionally inject the `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any` in constructor in customer-edit.component.ts based on how I access the screen behaviour to prevent this error?

Comment: Have you tried `@Optional` dectorator?

Comment: yeah, that seems the right way to do it, Thanks alot @yurzui

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to add `MatDialogRef` in component providers. The example is provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824504/11732146).